# Photo gallieries that have support for multiple albums and for comments?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-gallery

I'm looking for a photo gallery(jquery/JavaScript probably?) that supports having multiple albums, and for comments. Just needs to display the comments and have a box to enter the comment, and i can handle storing them in db easy enough.

Any that are similar to facebook would be great since everyone uses it and it would be intuitive to them.

edit: This will be for a web app using asp.net mssql server 2008 r2 but i could use any platform as long as i can communicate with the mssql db

Comment: @Andy Ray I have no problem with server interaction... and i'm not sure what's wrong with asking if there are any galleries that are similar to facebook vs just asking for image galleries? our users are not the most tech savy and the more familiar to them, the better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is a little late- but I think this may be what you were looking for:

http://www.jqueryrain.com/?t2bpYeU2

EDIT-

In an effort to keep this question current- this just came out recently and may be better than original plugin: http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-facebook-gallery/full_screen_preview/3879813?ref=jqueryrain

EDIT [Sept. 7th 2013] - Albumize recently came out. Another option for anyone reading. http://palerdot.github.io/albumize/

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this writing [minishowcase](http://minishowcase.net/) and [qGallery](http://qgallery.quadrifolia.de/) seem to be the more popular multi-album jquery/javascript libraries. I believe they both have some php running somewhere inside as well.

If you are averse to php for any reason and want straight javascript, css, and html try checking out [JonDesign's Smooth Gallery](http://smoothgallery.jondesign.net/showcase/gallery-set/). It too is open source and allows for multiple albums (albeit not as aesthetically pleasing as the first two and does not  have native comment plug-in, it is very straight forward code and can easily integrate with a jquery comment plug in's such as [Easy Comment](http://www.jswidget.com/lab/easy-comment.html)).

Edit: Also check out [TN3](http://www.tn3gallery.com/getting-started-dividing-images-into-albums/). They apparently support multiple albums but I have never used it as it is kind of expensive for a jQuery license.

Answer (score 0):

I do know that it is an older post but I would like to add a pure javascript solution for any following visitors of this post.
The [gambarize plugin](http://gambarize.klickagent.ch/) is running solely with client side javascript and there is no need for any backend language being used. (Therefore it is not possible to support comments)

Basically it is possible to create a **div structure** as the following:

```
 <a href="data/album_simple/wave.jpg" data-img-thumb="data/album_simple/_meta/thumb_wave.png" title="Wave, Bali" class="gmbz"></a>
 <a href="data/album_simple/mountains.jpg" data-img-thumb="data/album_simple/_meta/thumb_mountains.png" title="Mountains, Shadow" class="gmbz"></a>

 <div class="gmbz" data-title="Album1">
    <div class="gmbz" data-title="Nested">
        <div class="gmbz" data-title="Inner">
                <a href="data/album_simple/wave.jpg" data-img-thumb="data/album_simple/_meta/thumb_wave.png" title="Wave, Bali" class="gmbz"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="gmbz" data-title="Empty" data-cover="data/Black-287.png"></div>

    <a href="data/album_simple/field.jpg" data-img-thumb="data/album_simple/_meta/thumb_field.png" title="" class="gmbz"></a>
    <a href="data/album_simple/sea.jpg" data-img-thumb="data/album_simple/_meta/thumb_sea.png" title="Sea, Bali" class="gmbz"></a>
</div>
```

It will end up in:

[image: gambarize_javascript_album_image_gallery_plugin]

**Explanation**

- Every "div" represents an album (including nested album support).
- Every "a" represents a picture link, which will be the image itself: The attribute "href" is the image wich will be shown when you click on the thumbnail inside the gallery. Whereas the thumbnail image can be specified through the "data-img-thumb" tag
- Visit the example described: [generate image gallery with albums using javascript](http://gambarize.klickagent.ch/en/current/examples/parsing-basic/)

[Link to the plugin home page](http://gambarize.klickagent.ch/)